# Want to Draw simple shapes like circle , rectangle in visualstudio 2010 console c++

Tags: c++

Hya,

sorry for newbie question , i am trying to create simple circle in VS2010 console c++, also i looked in google but some provides library , some provides source code msoftcon.h etc , but still i am unable to draw a simple circle.The one msoftcon builds successfully but still it doesn't draw a circle just fills up the console window with 'U'

i'd be pleased if someone can help me with this.

thanks

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? The title of the question seems to imply you are trying to draw in console.

Comment: I want a source code for console c++ to do this without any library or if library provided , give me the tut please so that i can draw it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Circles as graphics objects
//Code from R. Lafore "OOP with C++
//
#include "msoftcon.h"           //for graphics function

struct circle
   {
   int xCo, yCo;                //coordinates of center
   int radius;
   color fillcolor;             //color
   fstyle fillstyle;            //fill pattern
   };

void circle_draw(circle c)
   {
   set_color(c.fillcolor);              //set color
   set_fill_style(c.fillstyle);         //set fill pattern
   draw_circle(c.xCo, c.yCo, c.radius); //draw solid circle
   }

int main()
   {
   init_graphics();                     //initialize graphics system

   circle c1 = {15, 7, 5, cBLUE, X_FILL};
   circle c2 = {41, 12, 7, cRED, O_FILL};
   circle c3 = {65, 18, 4, cGREEN, MEDIUM_FILL};

   circ_draw(c1);                       //draw circles
   circ_draw(c2);
   circ_draw(c3);
   set_cursor_pos(1, 25);               //cursor to lower left corner

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Yes , i tried this source code but console windows gets fully filled with character 'U' , no circle appears :(

Answer (score 0):

If I read this question correctly, you cannot draw "shapes" in any console or terminal "window." They are text-only. ASCII "art" does not count. :-)

HTH